How to change aria attribute with Jquery?
I have the following code where I would like to change the aria-describedby attribute to match the text in the <h3></h3> contained in that div. I need to identify each div by the .slick-slide class.

Note that I typically have 3 - 6 divs in a page with the slick-slide class.

<div class="cards__card cards__card--1 cards__slide section--light slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" role="tabpanel" id="slick-slide00" aria-describedby="slick-slide-control00">
    <div class="cards__slide-wrapper self-center">
        <h3 class="section__header cards__header heading heading--h3 ">--- HEADER ---</h3>
        <div class="cards__item cards__item--copy">
            <p> ---  SAMPLE TEXT ---</p>
        </div>
        <div class="cards__pagination cards__pagination--black">
            <p class="copy--disclaimer">1 / 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

I have tried the following to no avail:
$('div .slick-slide').each(function () {
    var h3 = $(this).closest("h3").text(); 
    $(this).attr("aria-describedby", h3);
});

Thank you in advance!

div .slick-slide should probably be div.slick-slide. The space means to look for a descendant of a div, but .slick-slide is the class of the div itself.

.closest() should be .find(). closest() looks for a containing element, not something that's contained within.

aria-describedby expects a list of other elements' id, not just any text.

jQuery's .closest() searches up the hierarchy whereas you want to search within the .slick-slide container.
Use .find() instead to search within an element.
As mentioned by several comments, the aria-describedby is not a free text attribute. Its value should be a list of...

the ids of the elements that describe the object.

I would approach this by retrieving or creating the <h3> ID and assign that to the attribute.
Also you might not definitely don't need jQuery


document.querySelectorAll('.slick-slide[id]').forEach((c) => {
  const heading = c.querySelector('h3');
  if (heading) {
    if (!heading.id) {
      heading.id = `${c.id}--heading`;
    }
    c.setAttribute('aria-describedby', heading.id);
  }
  
  console.log('aria-describedby:', c.getAttribute('aria-describedby'));
});
<div
  class="cards__card cards__card--1 cards__slide section--light slick-slide slick-current slick-active"
  data-slick-index="0"
  aria-hidden="false"
  tabindex="0"
  role="tabpanel"
  id="slick-slide00"
  aria-describedby="slick-slide-control00"
>
  <div class="cards__slide-wrapper self-center">
    <h3 class="section__header cards__header heading heading--h3">
      --- HEADER ---
    </h3>
    <div class="cards__item cards__item--copy">
      <p>--- SAMPLE TEXT ---</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cards__pagination cards__pagination--black">
      <p class="copy--disclaimer">1 / 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Thank you Phil. I tried both versions of your code, but neither is working for me. Don't understand why, it looks good to me
edit, nevermind, it works! Thank you!

I’m downvoting for now, as the code might do what it’s intended, but setting plain text as the value for an attribute ending with by is invalid. An id is required.

@Andy I have updated the answer with a correct aria-describedby value
